# Initializing unknown number of keys with specific values in a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

This is a kind of best practices question. Performance is important.

I have a list of strings, number of strings are not a constant number (may change from query to query). I wish to create a dictionary of these strings as keys and assing them a static value (which is constant and will same for all keys in the list). Like:

```
my_keys = ['AKey', 'AnotherKey', 'OneMore']

default_Value = dict({'count':0, 'basePrice': 0})
```

Expected Output:

```
{'AKey': {'count':0, 'basePrice': 0}, 'AnotherKey': {'count':0, 'basePrice': 0}, 'OneMore': {'count':0, 'basePrice': 0}}
```

Each value dictionary (`{'count':0, 'basePrice': 0}`) must be a separate object, not references of a single dictionary object.

I am looking for something **except** `for` loops.

I tried the following and it works when the number of keys are known.

```
dict(zip(my_keys, [dict(), dict(), dict()]))
```

But since the number of items in `my_keys` will change, this approaches fail.

Comment: Why do you want something **except** a loop? Best practice is either `.fromkeys()` (for immutables) or a dict comprehension (e.g. a loop).

Comment: Are dictionary comprehensions allowed (I don't see why not)? Also python version?

Comment: I suspect the OP would prefer to avoid a `for` statement because it cannot be used in an expression.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i know, but I am wondering if there is some other methods, since in `itertools` and in some other modules, ther are a lot of `magic-functions` and I wonder if there is one that can be used with objects which are called-by-references (like `dict` and `list`). @jamylak python version added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot avoid a loop; a dict comprehension is the best practice for creating a dictionary from a sequence of keys with a mutable value:

```
{key: {'count':0, 'basePrice': 0} for key in my_keys}
```

For Python 2.6 and earlier, use a generator expression and the `dict()` constructor:

```
dict((key, {'count':0, 'basePrice': 0}) for key in my_keys)
```

For completion's sake, for a default value that is not mutable, [`dict.fromkeys()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) is the better and faster alternative.

Answer (score 2):

A dict comprehension is what you would typically use for this:

```
{key: default_Value.copy() for key in my_keys}
```

Note that you need to copy `default_value` to avoid the same dict instance getting reused for all keys.

Answer (score 2):

Shallow copies, as suggested by the other answers, *may* not be good enough:

```
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> my_keys = ['AKey', 'AnotherKey', 'OneMore']
>>> default_Value = dict({'count':0, 'basePrice': 0})
>>> {k: deepcopy(default_Value) for k in my_keys}
{'OneMore': {'count': 0, 'basePrice': 0}, 'AKey': {'count': 0, 'basePrice': 0}, 'AnotherKey': {'count': 0, 'basePrice': 0}}
```

This is assuming you don't know your `default_Value` in advance eg. you can just plug in `{'count':0, 'basePrice': 0}` straight into a dictionary comprehension as shown by @MartijnPieters, which would be better in that case

As suggested by @gnibbler it might be faster to use `pickle.loads` in the dict comp.

```
>>> import pickle
>>> default_Value = dict({'count':0, 'basePrice': 0})
>>> _default_Value = pickle.dumps(default_Value)
>>> {k: pickle.loads(_default_Value) for k in my_keys}
{'OneMore': {'count': 0, 'basePrice': 0}, 'AKey': {'count': 0, 'basePrice': 0}, 'AnotherKey': {'count': 0, 'basePrice': 0}}
```

Comment: May be faster to make a `pickle.dumps` and `pickle.loads` in the comprehension instead of making lots of deepcopies

Comment: @gnibbler You should submit that as your own answer since it's a different solution but I added that and community wikied it anyway

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with

```
dct = defaultdict(lambda: {'count':0, 'basePrice': 0})
```

Explanation: it doesn't make sense to pre-populate the dict with the values which you don't use. And if you do, `defaultdict` will create them for you on the fly. I don't think anything can beat this performance-wise.

Comment: It doesn't yet have keys? :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: `dct['foobar']['count'] += 555` - works for me.

Comment: @thg435 Performance-wise it could be faster since you avoid resizing if you don't have to add any more keys

Answer (score -1):

```
dict(itertools.product(my_keys,[default_Value]))
```

Comment: This is going to reuse the same `default_Value` each time